# WordPress: Can't set slug because image with same name exists

Tags: php, wordpress

I've created a page which needs to have the slug `/replay`.

When saving out this page, I've realised that it saves it as `/replay-8`, meaning 7 other instances of `replay` exist.

I took a look at my pages, there's no other pages that have `/replay` in its slug. Then, I tried accessing `/replay-7` to see what it looks like and it took me to `/uploads/2021/02/replay-7.svg`

I have no redirects in place, nor any plugins, so is this happening out the box with WordPress?

I don't want to change filenames as a solution as it'll break anywhere those images are used.

Comment: I have same issue. Is this resolved? did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to rename the svg files or come up with another slug for the page.

Wordpress uses the Post Name to generate the plug as can be seen [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_unique_post_slug/)

Alternatively you'll need to look at a plugin.

Also, you may need to bear in mind that if you delete the media files, they still exist in the database so you would get replay-8 unless you clean up the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the image from the media browser and re-upload it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32284946)